# Netflix OSS Zuul serviceId is not working for us

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I recently discovered, that our Zuul is configured with specific URL and not with the eureka serviceId. Changing it was not successful. I'm probably missing something. This is my config:

## application.yml

```
spring:
    application:
      name: zuul
eureka:
    client:
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://eureka:8080/eureka/v2/
zuul:
  ignoredServices: '*'
  routes:
      geoserver: /geoserver/**
      file:
          path: /file/**
          serviceId: file-service
      metadata:
          path: /metadata/**
          serviceId: metadata-service
      websuite: /websuite/**
ribbon:
    websuite:
        enabled: false
```

## ZuulApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableZuulProxy
public class ZuulApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ZuulApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

## Eureka connections

[image: eureca connections]

## Stacktrace

This happens, when I call the main page:
http://dockerIp/websuite/

```
zuul_1           | com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:134) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.M5.jar!/:1.1.0.M5]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.M5.jar!/:1.1.0.M5]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:96) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:116) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:81) ~[zuul-core-1.1.0.jar!/:1.1.0]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:158) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequestInternal(ZuulController.java:43) [spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.M5.jar!/:1.1.0.M5]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845) [spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:237) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:112) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103) [spring-boot-actuator-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.3.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.4.RELEASE]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_91]
zuul_1           |  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_91]
zuul_1           |  at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar!/:8.0.32]
zuul_1           |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
zuul_1           | Caused by: com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: websuite failed and no fallback available.
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:806) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:790) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:99) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnFallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1521) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$FallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1411) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:314) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:306) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7710) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:100) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$3.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1012) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnRunHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1480) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$ExecutionHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1376) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:297) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:289) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7710) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$1.call(AbstractCommand.java:384) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$1.call(AbstractCommand.java:363) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7710) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$ObservableCommand$1.call(AbstractCommand.java:1140) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$ObservableCommand$1.call(AbstractCommand.java:1136) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:7804) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:7772) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.internal.operators.BlockingOperatorToFuture.toFuture(BlockingOperatorToFuture.java:57) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.toFuture(BlockingObservable.java:400) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.queue(HystrixCommand.java:379) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand.execute(HystrixCommand.java:335) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:119) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.M5.jar!/:1.1.0.M5]
zuul_1           |  ... 67 common frames omitted
zuul_1           | Caused by: com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: websuite
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.loadbalancer.LoadBalancerContext.getServerFromLoadBalancer(LoadBalancerContext.java:468) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.1.0.jar!/:2.1.0]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:184) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.1.0.jar!/:2.1.0]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.loadbalancer.reactive.LoadBalancerCommand$1.call(LoadBalancerCommand.java:180) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.1.0.jar!/:2.1.0]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:7710) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber$1.call(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:134) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.enqueue(TrampolineScheduler.java:80) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.schedulers.TrampolineScheduler$InnerCurrentThreadScheduler.schedule(TrampolineScheduler.java:59) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:86) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.internal.operators.OperatorRetryWithPredicate$SourceSubscriber.onNext(OperatorRetryWithPredicate.java:49) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:46) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.internal.util.ScalarSynchronousObservable$1.call(ScalarSynchronousObservable.java:35) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:162) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable$2.call(Observable.java:154) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:7804) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:7772) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.blockForSingle(BlockingObservable.java:432) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at rx.observables.BlockingObservable.single(BlockingObservable.java:331) ~[rxjava-1.0.14.jar!/:1.0.14]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:102) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.1.0.jar!/:2.1.0]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.client.AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.executeWithLoadBalancer(AbstractLoadBalancerAwareClient.java:81) ~[ribbon-loadbalancer-2.1.0.jar!/:2.1.0]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RestClientRibbonCommand.forward(RestClientRibbonCommand.java:135) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.M5.jar!/:1.1.0.M5]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RestClientRibbonCommand.run(RestClientRibbonCommand.java:106) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.M5.jar!/:1.1.0.M5]
zuul_1           |  at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RestClientRibbonCommand.run(RestClientRibbonCommand.java:1) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.1.0.M5.jar!/:1.1.0.M5]
zuul_1           |  at com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$1.call(HystrixCommand.java:294) ~[hystrix-core-1.4.23.jar!/:1.4.23]
zuul_1           |  ... 113 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Does the service id actually match the service id in eureka? Also please explain what happens currently (maybe with some stack trace) and show a screenshot of the eureka registrations.

Comment: Yes, they match. After changing url to serviceId, I started getting "forwarding error" from inside my zuul container.

Comment: Is there a service called `websuite`. As that is what it is failing at.

Comment: yes, there is. It is listed in the eureka screenshot aswell

Comment: I'm not sure but aren't those things case sensitive? `websuite` != `WEBSUITE`....

Comment: I checked the code, where we register the websuite at eureka, ist all lowercase. Eureka just displays caps.